# ¿como insertar el nuevo valor de input cuando este input se llena automáticamente de otros input,angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

tengo un problema intento insertar el valor de un input(type number) que se llena de otros input que se multiplican entre ellos. el valor de la multiplicación se guarda en el input que quiero insertar en la base datos(firebase) y este valor no se inserta.

```
<input  class="form-control" id="peso" type="number" placeholder="Envio Por Gramos" ng-model="app.peso">
<select ng-model="app.continente" id="continente" class="form-control" ng-options="option as option.name for option in optionObjs track by option.cgramo"></select>

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Costo Total" type="number" id="total" ng-model="app.costo">
```

la multiplicacion la hago asi

```
    $("#peso").keyup(function () {
        if($("#peso").val() && $("#continente").val()){
            var totaluno = $("#peso").val() * $("#continente").val();

            $("#total").val(totaluno);
        }
    });

    $("#continente").change(function () {
            if($("#peso").val() && $("#continente").val()){
                    var totaluno = $("#peso").val() * $("#continente").val();

                    $("#total").val(totaluno);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Demasiadas inconsistencias en tu código; estas obteniendo el valor mediante JQuery de los input cuando perfectamente lo puedes hacer mediante el $scope, por algo utilizas ng-model en cada elemento. Además donde esta la insersión en sí? Yo solo puedo ver operaciones matemáticas

Answer (score 0):

Haz esto:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first_value" placeholder="primero">
<input type="text" ng-model="second_value" placeholder="segundo">
<input type="text" ng-model="total" ng-value="first_value * second_value" placeholder="total">
<button ng-click="multiplicacion()">Multiplicar</button>
```

Eso en el caso de hacerlo solo visual si lo quieres guardar entonces haz lo siguiente:

```
$scope.multiplicacion = function(){
     $scope.total = parseInt($scope.first_value) * parseInt($scope.second_value);
}
```